# I found a file wlwmanifest.xml in my website source folder

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-frontend

```
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="../preload/wlwmanifest.xml">
```

I want to know the use of this and if remove this file, how will this effect my website?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? How is this question related to HTML or CSS?

Comment: This is associated with WordPress - are you using WordPress or is this just code copied from a WP site? Have you done some research? There are quite a number of hints and answers and explanations out there is you search for wlwmanifest. Have a look around and if still stuck show us some code which malfunctions because of this link inclusion.

Comment: Yes this is related to wordpress and yes i copied this code. just want to know the internal working for wlwmanifest as it didn't changed anything at frontend to see me what diffrence does it made to the project. I had done some research on this but found this indicates that this website is mode through wordpress. @AHaworth

Comment: I codied this code to vs code as i am now using wordpress, i exculed wlwmanifest from my code. I don't think that it changed anything from frontend but in any case for future refrence wants to know if this affects anything internally. Thanks

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the problem is related to Wordpress, please also add the appropriate tags

Answer (score 0):

The wlwmanifest.xml file is a WordPress default file created for use with the discontinued program Windows Live Writer ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Writer ) You could safely remove it and operate your site.